# What to select in catalog in platform builder to include SQL CE in image for windows CE

Tags: sql-server-ce, platform-builder

What to select in catalog in platform builder to include SQL CE in image for windows CE.

I have selected Application and Services Development->Sql Compact but it is still giving following error.

`File or assembly name "system.data.sqlserverce version=3.5.0.0, culture..." or one of its dependencies, was not found`

While digging further found While digging further found [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150628053406/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BruceEitman/archive/2009/05/15/platform-builder--problems-with-.net-cf-3.5-and-windows.aspx)

Now the question is how to add support for SPI_GETPLATFORMNAME in your platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your second question:
You need to P/Invoke [`SystemParameterInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ee499131%28v=winembedded.80%29) from Coredll.dll. For examples on how to do this or maybe even an implementation, you can check:

- [OpennetCF SDF 1.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20111127215429/http://www.opennetcf.com:80/Default.aspx?tabid=65)(Scroll down) with its full source code
- Search [PInvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/)

Be aware that the product name is up to the OEM to fill in and not all OEMs do that.

Regarding the SQLCe - I am not certain that it is included with PB. You might need to install the CAB file seperately, but, again, I am not sure of this.